# Admin Worker resets Number input while typing

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have an admin component with a number field which holds data of a model. Loading & saving just works fine with the default shopware components. But if I am typing a value into this field while the admin worker is executed my input gets reseted to its original value. Even if I just wait without clicking out of the input field or into the next one, the same effect happens. The change event needs to be triggered to safe my new input value, otherwise "the admin worker kills it". How could this be connected? How can I avoid this effect, without deactivating the admin worker?

```html
    <sw-field
        v-model="values[value.id]"
        :label="value.name"
        type="number"
    />
```

I also tried to store the value to the object with registering and event subscription on @keydown.up or v-on:keydown="storeMaterial" but both didn't get triggered.

The predefined values of this array are preloaded from database (which I left out here) or predefined as 0 already

```js
 getValues() {
     let storedValue = 0; 
     this.values[value.id] = storedValue;
 },
```

also tried this.$set, with and without predefined null

```js
 getValues() {
     this.$set(this.values, value.id, null);
     let storedValue = 0; 
     this.$set(this.values, value.id, storedValue);
 },
```

Comment: only solution for me was to change input number to text, then there is no resetting on ticks

Answer (score 0):

That is odd but sounds like it could be related to non-reactive mutation of `values`. You have to initially set the keys for `values` otherwise their respective values will not be stored reactively and will be lost on a next tick. (which I assume is caused by the admin worker)

As an example inside your component:

```js
data() {
    return {
        originalValues: [{ id: 'foo', name: 'bar' }],
        values: {},
    };
},

created() {
    this.originalValues.forEach((value) => {
        if (this.values.hasOwnProperty(value.id)) {
            return;
        }

        // set to null initially, will make `this.values[value.id]` reactive
        this.$set(this.values, value.id, null);
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I edited my initial post showing the js code to load the array data, its already predefined with 0 or the database value, but both lead to the same behaviour

Comment: Have you tried `this.$set(this.values, value.id, storedValue);` instead of `this.values[value.id] = storedValue;`? This makes the difference of the value being reactive or not.

Comment: tried that too, but result stays the same. Maybe there is a way to register on the keydown on that element? Alternative to @keydown.up or v-on:keydown which didn't work